# HTML5 canvas draw section of image with rotation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I am busy writing a Texture Atlas class for my HTML5 games but,
I am having trouble with drawing a section of an image with rotation.

For example: extracting a soccer ball from the spritesheet and drawing it with rotation.

I've set up the following fiddle, where I draw an image rotated, and then a portion of the image, I just can't figure out how to do both at the same time :/

http://jsfiddle.net/9ztnF/10/

The section of code I need help with follows:

```js
targetX = 450;
targetY = 35;
context.save();
context.translate(targetX, targetY);
context.translate(halfWidth, halfHeight);
context.rotate(60 * TO_RADIANS);

// Help needed HERE!!!!! 

// draws full image rotated at half height
// context.drawImage(logoImage, -halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight);

// draws nothing that is visible
//context.drawImage(logoImage, -halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight, targetX, targetY, halfWidth, halfHeight);

context.restore();
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a part of the image doesn't impact rotation. Just draw you rotated image with source location/ scale, and destination location / scale properties :

```
//
// Draw rotated image
//
targetX = 50;
targetY = 35;
context.save();
context.translate(targetX, targetY); // move the origin to 50, 35
context.translate(halfWidth, halfHeight); // move across and down half the width and height of the image
context.rotate(60 * TO_RADIANS); // rotate around this point
context.drawImage(logoImage, halfWidth, halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight, 0, 0, halfWidth, halfHeight); // then draw the image back and up
context.restore();
```